# Set background of a stackpanel to an image in c#

Tags: windows-phone-7

I need to set the **Background** of a **Stackpanel** to some image in the resources.
I know that i should set the background as follows:

```
Stack.Background= image; // don't know of what type the image should be how to set it
```

Any help is appreciated,

Comment: Have you tried using an ImageBrush and are getting some kind of error? Or are you asking how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
string fileName = "/Background.png";
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Relative));
ImageBrush brush = new ImageBrush();
brush.ImageSource = image;
stack.Background = brush;
```

Answer (score 1):

[StackPanel.Background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.background%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) is of type Brush, and you'll need to create an [ImageBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) in order to display an image on the StackPanel.